# ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn. Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

In my WPF window, I have declared the following:

```
public List<Brand> BrandList;
```

and then in the constructor, the list is populated:

```
BrandList = new List<Brand>(EntityDao.GetInstance().GetProducts().Select(p => p.Brand).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b.Name));
```

Then in my XAML code, I have declared a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid <!-- Properties omitted--> >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BrandList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- Other columns omitted -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that my comboboxes are empty. By debugging, I have verified that the `BrandList` object holds more than 80 objects, all of which have defined a `ToString()` method.

The ItemsSource of the DataGrid is a simple ObservableCollection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any Debug Information if you set the traceLevel of your binding to high?: 

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BrandList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />

Comment: With tools like WPF inspector, you can check if your binding has error or not, it may help when you test a lot of things...

Comment: I get a lot of warnings ending with 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=33514934): Found data context element: <null> (OK)

Comment: and where you set the data context in your example?

Comment: I didn't. But isn't the RelativeSource enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding works with properties, and you declared a public member.
You should define your list like this:

```
public List<Brand> BrandList { get;set;}
```

Comment: it does. The datagrid is bound to an ObservableCollection

Comment: Try to fill the list before you call InitializeComponents() (or implement INPC)